Powershell Sort-Object is not sorting a PSCustomObject if explicitly casting the column to [double]
Edit: I've updated the code sample to remove confusing pseudocode and added a few comments in the code.
I apologize for the long code sample.  I tried to include pertinent information while cutting out unnecessary code.
I'm reading in a CSV file that is externally created; I don't have control over the column names.  It has "unusual" column names such as 'WEEKLY PERF' and '3-MONTH PERF'.  I am processing that file, filtering it in 3 separate ways, and mashing the results in an output CSV file.  That file is read via Excel Power Query as a "poor man's dashboard" and is manually reviewed; it does not serve as further input data.
The sort works fine for the 'WEEKLY PERF' column but does not sort the '3-MONTH PERF' column.
Here is an excerpt of the code.  The problem line is commented "this does not sort OK".
I admit this is difficult without being able to run the script, but I've pulled my hair out on this one, and Googled for hours before posting.  Any ideas are welcome and appreciated.
### Some of this code is pseudocode to shorten the length of the code ###

# Create metadata for easier program maintenance
$hash=@{}
$hash.AU=@{
    'ScanDir'       = 'SomePath1';
    'SortColumn'    = 'WEEKLY PERF';
}
$hash.US=@{
    'ScanDir'       = 'SomePath2';
    'SortColumn'    = '3-MONTH PERF';
}

foreach ($Key in $hash.Keys) {
    $dir  = $hash.$Key.ScanDir
    $file = $(Get-ChildItem "$dir\*.csv" | Sort-Object $PSItem -Descending)[0]  # get latest [yyyy-MM-dd] file
    if (!$file) {continue}

    $csv=Import-CSV "$file"

    # Get the header from the CSV row properties
    $hdr=$csv[0].PSObject.Properties.Name -join ","

    # Remove percent signs and convert to percentages
    $csv=$csv | ForEach-Object {
        $ht=[ordered]@{}
        foreach ($property in $_.PSObject.Properties) {
            $name =$property.Name
            $value=$property.Value
            if ($value -match "%") {
                $value=try {
                    # [double]$value.Replace("%", "") / 100
                    # [double]$value.Replace("%", "") / 100.0
                    # [float]$value.Replace("%", "") / 100
                    # [float]$value.Replace("%", "") / 100.0
                    $value.Replace("%", "") / 100       # <<<<< This is the one to use, don't explicitly cast
                    # $value.Replace("%", "") / 100.0
                } catch {
                    $value  # should never happen
                }
            }
            $ht["$name"]=$value
        }
        # Convert the hashtable to a PSCustomObject and stream the data to the pipeline
        [PSCustomObject]$ht
    }

    $SortColumn=$hash.$Key.SortColumn

    # I then filter the CSV three different ways and mash the results together into an output CSV
    # newbuys and newsells are for symbols already in TopPerformers list
    $newbuys  = $csv | Where-Object {$_.TopPerformer -eq 1 -and $_.NewBuy  -eq 1} | Sort-Object -Property $SortColumn -Descending
    $newsells = $csv | Where-Object {$_.TopPerformer -eq 1 -and $_.NewSell -eq 1} | Sort-Object -Property $SortColumn -Descending

    # potential buys are for symbols not already in TopPerformers list
    # (this has repeated code but I have left in for future maintainability)
    $potbuys = $csv
    if ($Key -eq "AU") {
        $potbuys = $potbuys | Where-Object {$_.TopPerformer -eq 0}
        $potbuys = $potbuys | Where-Object {$_.Direction -eq 1}
        $potbuys = $potbuys | Where-Object {[double]$_.'WEEKLY PERF'  -gt [double]$_.'CHG %'}
        $potbuys = $potbuys | Where-Object {[double]$_.'MONTHLY PERF' -gt [double]$_.'WEEKLY PERF'}
        $potbuys = $potbuys | Where-Object {[double]$_.'3-MONTH PERF' -gt [double]$_.'MONTHLY PERF'}
        $potbuys = $potbuys | Where-Object {[double]$_.'6-MONTH PERF' -gt [double]$_.'3-MONTH PERF'}
        $potbuys = $potbuys | Where-Object {[double]$_.'YTD PERF'     -gt [double]$_.'6-MONTH PERF'}
        # $potbuys = $potbuys | Where-Object {[double]$_.'YEARLY PERF'  -gt [double]$_.'YTD PERF'}
        $potbuys = $potbuys | Sort-Object -Property [double]$SortColumn -Descending
    } 
    elseif ($Key -eq "US") {
        $potbuys = $potbuys | Where-Object {$_.TopPerformer -eq 0}
        $potbuys = $potbuys | Where-Object {$_.Direction -eq 1}
        $potbuys = $potbuys | Where-Object {[double]$_.'WEEKLY PERF'  -gt [double]$_.'CHG %'}
        $potbuys = $potbuys | Where-Object {[double]$_.'MONTHLY PERF' -gt [double]$_.'WEEKLY PERF'}
        $potbuys = $potbuys | Where-Object {[double]$_.'3-MONTH PERF' -gt [double]$_.'MONTHLY PERF'}
        $potbuys = $potbuys | Where-Object {[double]$_.'6-MONTH PERF' -gt [double]$_.'3-MONTH PERF'}
        $potbuys = $potbuys | Where-Object {[double]$_.'YTD PERF'     -gt [double]$_.'6-MONTH PERF'}
        # $potbuys = $potbuys | Where-Object {[double]$_.'YEARLY PERF'  -gt [double]$_.'YTD PERF'}
        $potbuys = $potbuys | Sort-Object -Property [double]$SortColumn -Descending
    }

    $newbuys  = $newbuys  | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -UseQuotes Never -NoHeader
    $newsells = $newsells | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -UseQuotes Never -NoHeader
    $potbuys  = $potbuys  | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -UseQuotes Never -NoHeader

    # Add headers to the sections
    $newbuys  = "NEW BUYS", $newbuys
    $newsells = "`nNEW SELLS", $newsells
    $potbuys  = "`nPOTENTIAL BUYS", $potbuys
    
    # Need to account for empty data in arrays by explicitly writing out the header as the first row
    # (The filename begins with "@", it's not a token in the code)
    $hdr      | Out-File $(Join-Path $hash.$Key.ScanDir "@${Key}_Top_Performers_Scan.csv") -Force -Encoding ascii
    $newbuys  | Out-File $(Join-Path $hash.$Key.ScanDir "@${Key}_Top_Performers_Scan.csv") -Force -Encoding ascii -Append
    $newsells | Out-File $(Join-Path $hash.$Key.ScanDir "@${Key}_Top_Performers_Scan.csv") -Force -Encoding ascii -Append
    $potbuys  | Out-File $(Join-Path $hash.$Key.ScanDir "@${Key}_Top_Performers_Scan.csv") -Force -Encoding ascii -Append
}


What does the data look like.   Most likely the data is sorting as a string and not the format of the actual data.  Or the 3 Month Perf is using a different culture like using MM/DD/YY instead of DD/MM/YY.

Shouldn't the lines $potbuys = $potbuys | "a bunch of filtering in separate steps" and $potbuys = $potbuys | "etc" throw errors?

Attempting to cast the sort key name (which is a [string]) to a [double] won't work - you'll want PowerShell to treat the actual sort key value as a [double] instead.
Fortunately, Sort-Object takes calculated property expressions in place of property names:
... |Sort-Object -Property { $_.$SortKey -as [double]}

Now PowerShell has an opportunity to evaluate $_.$SortKey and resolve the column value before converting it to [double], and you should see it sorting accordingly

I believe the $SortColumn variable should resolve first, such that:
Sort-Object -Property [double]$SortColumn -Descending
is equivalent to:
Sort-Object -Property [double]'3-MONTH PERF' -Descending
which is the name of the desired property.

@Scott You can believe whatever you want, both examples are meaningless - because of PowerShell's contextual parsing mechanics, passing [double]$SortColumn as the literal argument to -Property will cause Sort-Object to look for a sort key with the literal property name "[double]3-PERF MONTH", which obviously doesn't exist, resulting in a meaningless sort order. You can see for yourself by using [double]3-PERF MONTH as the actual property name

$SortColumn = '3-MONTH PERF'; $x=(1..10) | % {[PSCustomObject]@{'[double]3-MONTH PERF'=[math]::Round($(Get-Random -Mini 0 -Maximum 1.0000),4)}}; $x |Sort-Object -Property [double]$SortColumn

Thanks for correcting my misunderstanding and the link.  I'll study it and try to internalize it.  I've also corrected a bug in my answer below.  $x | Sort-Object -Property { '3-MONTH PERF' -as [double] } -Descending should be $x | Sort-Object -Property { $_.'3-MONTH PERF' -as [double] } -Descending

OT:  How do you add the grey bolding in a comment?

@Scott Surround the code you want formatted with backticks ` - and yes -Property { $_.'3-MONTH PERF' -as [double]} will work (which is why my answer suggests doing just that ^_^)

I've solved this issue and wanted to give the details in case others find this topic in a future search.  Note that I edited the code slightly from the original post, but hopefully my comments below will make sense even if they don't quite match the edited code.
The source data is a CSV file with columns containing % signs, for example 63.24%, -12.34%, etc.  So PS would treat those columns as strings.  I need to sort using numeric collation.
This section of the code changes that data to numeric data:
# Remove percent signs and convert to percentages
$csv=$csv | ForEach-Object {
    $ht=[ordered]@{}
    foreach ($property in $_.PSObject.Properties) {
        $name =$property.Name
        $value=$property.Value
        if ($value -match "%") {
            $value=try {
                # [double]$value.Replace("%", "") / 100
                # [double]$value.Replace("%", "") / 100.0
                # [float]$value.Replace("%", "") / 100
                # [float]$value.Replace("%", "") / 100.0
                $value.Replace("%", "") / 100       # <<<<< This is the one to use, don't explicitly cast
                # $value.Replace("%", "") / 100.0
            } catch {
                $value  # should never happen
            }
        }
        $ht["$name"]=$value
    }
    # Convert the hashtable to a PSCustomObject and stream the data to the pipeline
    [PSCustomObject]$ht
}

I added the extra code for debugging.  I discovered that PS converted the data to double by default, and no additional casting was required.  Dividing by 100 or 100.0 made no difference.  Explicitly casting to [float] was a bad idea and resulted in precision differences.  After conversion all data was 4 decimal place precision, eg. 0.6324, -0.1234, etc.
My previous code that was not working correctly was:
$potbuys = $potbuys | Sort-Object -Property [double]$SortColumn -Descending

Which can also be coded as:
$potbuys = $potbuys | Sort-Object -Property [double]'3-MONTH PERF' -Descending

I confirmed that the data was already [double] by using a breakpoint in the debugger and running:
$potbuys.$SortColumn[0].GetType(); $potbuys.$SortColumn[0]

First, the explicit casting in the Sort-Object cmdlet was redundant, since I'd already converted the data type in the above step.  Second, the explicit casting caused the problem, and removing the [double] fixed the issue.
TBH I don't know why explicitly casting a column that is already double to double caused an issue but it did.
I was able to replicate the issue with this code:
$x=(1..10) | % {[PSCustomObject]@{'3-MONTH PERF'=[math]::Round($(Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 1.0000),4)}}
$x
$x | Sort-Object -Property [double]'3-MONTH PERF' -Descending
$x | Sort-Object -Property { '3-MONTH PERF' -as [double] } -Descending  # <<< bug
$x | Sort-Object -Property '3-MONTH PERF' -Descending  # <<< works

Edit: The above code has a bug.
$x | Sort-Object -Property { '3-MONTH PERF' -as [double] } -Descending

Should be:
$x | Sort-Object -Property { $_.'3-MONTH PERF' -as [double] } -Descending

Using a more "typical" column name eg. FOO did not matter.
I tried the same thing with a regular array and it works as expected:
$x=(1..10) | % {[math]::Round($(Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 1.0000),4)}
$x | Sort-Object -Property [double]$_ -Descending
$x | Sort-Object -Property $_ -Descending

